# Extending HTML Elements Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was interested in extending native HTML attributes and stumbled upon quite a few ways of doing this: `ComponentPropsWithoutRef`, `ComponentPropsWithRef`, `ComponentProps` and `ButtonHTMLAttributes`, which seem to work exactly the same. Also saw `HTMLAttributes`, which doesn't really work, and `HTMLProps`, which throws `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined'.`, unless I spread `...props` first. So, I was just wondering if the first four can be used interchangeably or I made a mistake somewhere...

I was it on this example:

```
interface ButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  submitButton: boolean;
}

const RefButton = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  ({ submitButton, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <button ref={ref} type={submitButton ? "submit" : "button"} {...props}>
        Test
      </button>
    );
  },
);

function PlainButton({ submitButton, ...props }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button type={submitButton ? "submit" : "button"} {...props}>
      Test
    </button>
  );
}

function App() {
  const testRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <RefButton disabled ref={testRef} submitButton />
      <PlainButton submitButton={false} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I find it hard to follow what is the issue here, can you reword your question?

Comment: Is there any difference between using `ComponentPropsWithoutRef`, `ComponentPropsWithRef`, `ComponentProps` and `ButtonHTMLAttributes` to extend default HTML props? Because from what I've tried, they were working exactly the same way, unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: I've found some hint in [@types/react](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L813), a comment above `ComponentProps`: _"NOTE: prefer ComponentPropsWithRef, if the ref is forwarded, or ComponentPropsWithoutRef when refs are not supported."_.